# Global Ajax error handler with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

When my website was 100% jQuery, I used to do this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    global: true,
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
           window.location = "./index.html";
        }
    }
});
```

to set a global handler for 401 errors. Now, I use angularjs with `$resource` and `$http` to do my (REST) requests to the server. Is there any way to similarly set a global error handler with angular?

Comment: Is it a possible duplicate of [AngularJS Failed Resource GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598097/angularjs-failed-resource-get)?

Comment: No, we want to do a global error 401 handler for the application

Comment: lol, have you considered that what you want but with a different http status (which you can change)? Anyhow, pkozlowski.opensource's answer shows you how to do it

Comment: No, it is a lot more like the answer of Justen...this is not a duplicate with the question you're talking

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I'm also building a website with angular and I came across this same obstacle for global 401 handling. I ended up using http interceptor when I came across this blog post. Maybe you'll find it as helpful as I did.

["Authentication in AngularJS (or similar) based application."](http://www.espeo.pl/1-authentication-in-angularjs-application/), *espeo software*

**EDIT: final solution**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives'], function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

    var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function (scope, $q) {

        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            var status = response.status;

            if (status == 401) {
                window.location = "./index.html";
                return;
            }
            // otherwise
            return $q.reject(response);

        }

        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }

    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Comment: It look great! I'll try it this afternoon

Comment: I noticed at the bottom you begin the `$routeProvider.when(` function.  Usually, that's in a `.config(`.  Can this / should this exist outside the `.config(`?

Comment: I believe it can be placed outside the .config(), but that's where I store all my .whens()

Comment: Note that on the [docs for $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#responseinterceptors) they suggest creating a servicerather than doing it inline as above

Comment: can I use a similar approach for resources? I want to expect success : false to be failure but from a resource's point of view that's a 200 HTTP. Take a look at my question as well please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038702/angular-resource-error-handling-how-can-i-treat-a-success-false-that-comes-f/17038902?noredirect=1#17038902

Comment: Need to return $q.reject(response); when status == 401, to avoid a noisy angular error

Comment: good stuff but should use `$location.path('#/')` not the global `window.location` object

Comment: @daniellmb. It depends. If you actually want to go to another page, not just change the view then you should actually use $window. If your login page is just another view and controller with your angular then you can use $location.path

Comment: @uriDium right my point was to use the angular provided objects so you can mock and test.

Comment: $httpProvider.responseInterceptors is now deprecated. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#description_interceptors.

Comment: In success you need to return like `return response || $q.when(response);` so that if the response is empty then also a promise object is returned.

Comment: The blog article URL that Justen referred has been changed to:  http://www.espeo.pl/1-authentication-in-angularjs-application/

Comment: this probably won't work with agressive minification but the idea is good

Answer (score 77):

Please note that responseInterceptors have been deprecated with Angular 1.1.4. 
Below you can find an excerpt based on the [official docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http), showing the new way to implement interceptors.

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },

   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise;
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

This is how it looks in my project using Coffeescript:

```
angular.module("globalErrors", ['appStateModule']).factory "myHttpInterceptor", ($q, $log, growl) ->
  response: (response) ->
    $log.debug "success with status #{response.status}"
    response || $q.when response

  responseError: (rejection) ->
    $log.debug "error with status #{rejection.status} and data: #{rejection.data['message']}"
    switch rejection.status
      when 403
        growl.addErrorMessage "You don't have the right to do this"
      when 0
        growl.addErrorMessage "No connection, internet is down?"
      else
        growl.addErrorMessage "#{rejection.data['message']}"

    # do something on error
    $q.reject rejection

.config ($provide, $httpProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor')
```

Comment: But you will have no xhr data or other useful info in responseError interceptor. It's even unusable to decide if it's recoverable.

Comment: @zw0rk You will... inside of `responseError`, `rejection` has everything you need.

Comment: Does that last line, `$httpProvider...` get wrapped in a `config()` block?

Comment: indeed, I've edited my answer to show how I did it in my project using Coffeescript. Use http://js2coffee.org/ if you prefer it in Javascript.

Comment: Shouldn't all the reference to `response` under the `responseError` function actually be references to `rejection` (or maybe the parameter should have its name changed to `response`?

Comment: I created a fiddle with different edge cases (Black Hole serivce, Response Codes etc.): http://jsfiddle.net/dv1vobsn/

Answer (score 16):

Create the file `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/config/httpInterceptor.js" ></script>` with this content:

```
(function(){
  var httpInterceptor = function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q) {
      return {
        response: function (response) {
          return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
          if(rejection.status === 401) {
            // you are not autorized
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
  };
  angular.module("myModule").config(httpInterceptor);
}());
```

Comment: @ThilakRaj the above code should run on every http request. So make two breakpoints in Chrome, one on the ´return response´ line and one on the ´return $q.reject´ to check that it runs as it should.