# How to handle code status like 202, 204, and so on with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

according to the documentation of angular http API "error" method is called when server response status is 400 and above.

does this mean that when ever I want to check for status codes of 202, 204 ... to 400 I need to check them with If( status = 202 ) , if (status 204) ...

isn't there something like onViolationContrains like in GWT RPC, and RequestFactory ?, if not, how do you this.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971213/error-401-handling-with-angularjs

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I think that response interceptors might be what you are looking for. Check the "response interceptors" section in [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

From the linked documentation:

> For **purposes of global error handling**, authentication or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous preprocessing of received responses, it is
>   desirable to be able to intercept responses for http requests before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests.