# Angular Resource Error Handling : How can I treat a success : false that comes from a resource?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Let's say I have an angular service that has this method:

```
this.query = function(params, successFn, errorFn) {
        return $resource(backendUrl + '/myresource.json')
        .query(params, successFn, errorFn);
};
```

Sometimes the rest API fails, so the errorFn is called. However, sometimes I might be sending invalid parameters and the Rest API would send a `HTTP 200` with `success : false`. I know this is a bad practice but since the API is not to be changed, I'm left handling the error in the success callback.

As you may know, the success callback will always give me an array, so the JSON response :

```
{
    'message' : 'invalid parameter x',
    'success' : false
}
```

Would be exposed as the first parameter in the successFn as :

```
[ { 0 : 'i', '1' : 'n', '2' : 'v' .... }, {....} ]
```

Is there any way to get access to the original content returned from the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) instead of resource

```
// $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
var promise = $http({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    params: params
}).then(function (response) {
    //do what you want to do with the response here
    //to see what response contains print JSON.stringify(response)
});
```