# How to get ensureLoggedIn working with routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, route-provider

I'm working on a node.js application, using Angular.js, passport and connect-ensure-login.

Only on refresh (F5), does the redirect in ensureLoggedIn seem to work and I get to the login page, otherwise I think the routeProvider for the one-page app just takes over for normal click and I get to ***localhost:3000/users*** still with the 500 error from '/api/users'.

How can I get **connect-ensure-login** (ensureLoggedIn) working for both direct path and click-through?

```
app.get('/users', ensureLoggedIn('/login'))
```

For APIs, I'm using

```
app.get('/api/users', 
    passport.authenticate('bearer'),
    ...
```

routeProvider snippet for the application:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            })
            ...
```

References:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-ensure-login

http://passportjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to go about solving this issue by making use of the `$httpProvider.interceptors`.

In your case you could catch the `500` error coming from `/api/users` (though probably better to return a `401` or `403`) and have an interceptor kick in and take the user to `/login`.

Here's the official doc:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Here's a more specific example:

http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/75952317665/angularjs-interceptors-globally-handle-401-and-other

And here's a similar answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764801/115015

Comment: Looks like I should just chuck connect-ensure-login... ?

Comment: I guess it would depend on what you're ultimately after.  For my app I keep it around as I need it to cover the case for full page reloads for parts of my app which don't make use of Angular routing.  If your app is completely governed by Angular routing then you may want to just stick with your server side returning HTTP error codes that your routing + interceptors can handle.

Comment: Thanks Brian, eventually I just went for catching the error codes and using the http interceptor.