# AngularJS. Adding global AJAX error handler if it is not already defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, interceptor

How I can set global AJAX handler which will be called only if I not already defined error handler for specific AJAX call?

Some of my ajax call really need to do some logic if error was occurred (for example re-enable button), but for some AJAX I only need to show error message if error was occurred.

For example this code is not define any error handler for AJAX call, so I want to apply to this call global error handler where I will just show error message:

```
user.$delete().then(function () {
    // on success
});
```

But this AJAX call already define error handler, and I don't want to apply global handler to it:

```
    $scope.deleteButtonEnabled = false;
    user.$delete().then(function () {
        // on success
    }, function(err) {   
        // Do some stuff and then show error message     
        $scope.deleteButtonEnabled = true;        
        alert('Error' + JSON.stringify(err))
    });
```

Comment: So ultimately you need to show the error message on every failure, in one place instead of repeating the error showing logic everywhere?

Comment: @PSL exactly. But if I have some different error handling logic I want to be able to specify it and ignore global handler for this specific call.

Comment: Are you using angular http or some thing else ?, you could make use of interceptors if you are using angular one

Comment: @PSL yes, I guess I will use something like described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11972128/921193 But I don't know how to check if currently intercepting request already has a error handler

Comment: Can you show your user Service? You can handle it through config

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) and some config in the http calls.

Define an interceptor:-

```
angular.service('HttpInterceptor', function($q){
  var service = {
     response:function(response) { //Only if you need
        //If you have to handle response data based errors you could do this here
         return $q.when(response);
      },
     responseError: function(response){
        if(!response.config.suppressGlobal){ //Handle error only if the global error handling is not suppressed
            //Handle Error based
            alert('Error' + response.status);
        }

        return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor'); //Push the interceptor here
}]);
```

In your service example, when you make the http or resource call, let the method take an optional boolean argument to suppress the global error handler, pass it along with the `config` dictionary argument of the http call:-

```
   app.service('userService', function(){
        this.getData = function(suppressGlobal){ //Take a flag to suppress globals
             return  http.get('...', {suppressGlobal:suppressGlobal}).. //Pass the flag in the config
        };
        this.delete = function(suppressGlobal){ //Take a flag to suppress globals
          return http.delete('...', {suppressGlobal:suppressGlobal}).. //Pass the flag in the config
        }
        this.add = function(suppressGlobal){//Take a flag to suppress globals
            return http.post('..', data, {suppressGlobal:suppressGlobal}).. //Pass the flag in the config
        }
   });
```

and when you make a call:-

```
   // Code that needs global error handling
    user.delete().then(function () { //just call your service method as is
       // on success
    });
```

In some other place:-

```
// Code that needs to suppress global error handling
user.delete(true).then(function () { //Pass true as argument to the delete which will supress global error handling.
    // on success
}, function(err) {   
    // Do some stuff and then show error message     
    $scope.deleteButtonEnabled = true;        
    alert('Error' + JSON.stringify(err))
});
```