# AngularJS: How to handle success and error call backs with ngResource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

The [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) does not give any idea about it.

My `REST` enpoint might throw error

```
$scope.delete = function(index) {
    Transaction.delete({transactionId: $scope.transactions[index].uuid})     
  };
```

I changed the above to following

```
$scope.delete = function(index) {
    Transaction.delete({transactionId: $scope.transactions[index].uuid})
      .success('transaction deleted');
  };
```

But it fails

```
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'success'
    at Object.TransactionController.$scope.delete (http://localhost:5000/static/app/js/controllers/transactionController.js:26:8)
    at http://localhost:5000/static/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6094:36
```

How can I handle `success` and `error` scenarios?

P.S. I am new to JavaScript

Comment: try adding a callback function to the `delete` method invocation, and see if it works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can pass in a success a error callback using the following formats depending on how you are using the Resource (taken from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource)):

> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

Your example is similar to the **non-get "class" actions** and would look something like this:

```
Transaction.delete({transactionId: $scope.transactions[index].uuid}, 
    function(successResult) {
        // do something on success
    }, function(errorResult) {
        // do something on error
        if(errorResult.status === 404) {            
        }
    }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11598097/1207991) is a related question regarding a failed GET resource.

Answer (score 4):

Pass in the success and fail callback functions as arguments.

```
Transaction.delete({transactionId: $scope.transactions[index].uuid}, 
                   function(data) {
                      // success
                   }, function(e) {
                      // failure
                   });
```

From the docs you linked:

> HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],
>   [error])
>   non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters],
>   postData, [success], [error])

Comment: what's the data type of 'e'?