# AngularJS ngResource delete event not calling callback

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I have this code:

```
dogsResource.delete({id: $stateParams.dogId}, angular.noop,
        function(value, responseHeaders){
            //Success
            console.log(value);
            console.log(responseHeaders);
        },
        function(httpResponse){
            //Error
            console.log(httpResponse);
        }
    );
```

The delete is **done**, the problem is that neither success nor error is being called. I've also tried using an instance (that means, to use $delete), but it didnt work either.

I tried testing the callbacks with other methods, such as get

```
$scope.dog = dogsResource.get({id: $stateParams.dogId}, function(value, res){
    console.log(value);
});
```

And it works. I don't know why that happen, since the dog is being deleted from database.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

dogResource code

```
// Return the dogs resource
.factory('dogsResource', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource("http://localhost:5000/dogs/:id",{id: "@id"},{update: {method: "PUT"}});
}])
```

**UPDATE 2**

I Found the error. It was in the RESTful API (Node js). The method was not sending anything to Angular, so no callback was triggered:

```
//DELETE - Delete a dog with specified ID
exports.deleteDog = function(req, res) {
    console.log('DELETE' + req.params.id);

    Dog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, dog) {
        dog.remove(function(err) {
            if(err) return res.status(500).send(err.message);
            console.log('Succesfully deleted.');
            res.status(200);
        })
    });
};
```

Replacing `res.status(200)` with `res.status(200).end()` got the callback triggered.

Thanks you all for your time.

Comment: I know it sounds obvious but should **angular.noop** be there at all?

Comment: @camden_kid The doc says that non http get actions should have a postData, and I dont need that. By the way, I've also tried with null, {} and even ignoring it.

Comment: Yep, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579201/angularjs-how-to-handle-success-and-error-call-backs-with-ngresource you're correct. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: None, as I said, the delete is done, but no log is printed.

Comment: What happens if you attempt to delete an **id** you know does not exist (e.g. {id: "test"})?

Comment: Thanks for that case, I found a little error with the angular.noop (It didnt work as I expected). When I attempt to delete an id that doesn't exist, the error callback works.

Comment: have you tried using the promise property? like this `dogsResource.delete({id: $stateParams.dogId}).$promise.then(function(value) { console.log('value', value)});`

Comment: I'm interested to know what the your browser's network tab shows when you perform this delete action.  When you make these resource calls, the network tab shows them as they occur.  Before going any further, I think it would behoove you to confirm if a response(success, failure, or anything) is even occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  suggest to you to not use

> res.status(200).end()

In fact usually when you delete an object with a REST service in expressJS, the common case is to send the deleted object as response, because it could be useful for the frontend to get this object (and to make sure that it's the good object).

So instead of use

> res.status(200).end()

use

> res.send(dog)

Or if you want to send an empty response, the status code for a delete operation should be :

> res.status(204).end()
>
> 204 NO CONTENT

Note that you don't need to set the status code by default it will be 200. So set status code to 200 is just useless.

And to finish an http response needs to be sent to close the request. The end method or the send method make that. Set a status code to a response http will never send anything to the frontend. That's why your angular callback was never fired.

So i suggest to you to add the tag expressjs to your question, because it's not an AngularJS problem but a real expressJS mistake.

Comment: You are right. I thought it was angular since the delete was done, but then I discovereded that it was in fact de Api. I'll check what you say, all other methods (get, save, etc) send a `res.send(dog)`, but delete was as I posted in the op. I'll add the tags.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the second argument is `angular.noop`:

```
dogsResource.delete({id: $stateParams.dogId}, angular.noop,
        function(value, responseHeaders){
            //Success
            console.log(value);
            console.log(responseHeaders);
        },
        function(httpResponse){
            //Error
            console.log(httpResponse);
        }
    );
```

According to the [ngResource Source Code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L594), if you set the second argument to a function (`angular.noop` **is** a function) then it will use the second argument as the success callback. Since the second argument is a no-operation, nothing will happen when it is called.

Try setting the second argument to `function (r) { console.log (r) }` and see what you get.

Comment: No, it is not that, as I said in the commentd of the op. Even changing as you say, the callback is not called.

Answer (score 2):

I'm recently working with ngResource. In my case, I've have used three parameters in that api call. Therefore, you could use

```
dogsResource.delete({id: $stateParams.dogId}, function(value, responseHeaders){
            //Success
            console.log(value);
            console.log(responseHeaders);
        },
        function(httpResponse){
            //Error
            console.log(httpResponse);
        }
    );
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use promise return by the `$resource` object. As $resource object by default return a promise object, and that promise object is available `.$promise` variable over that `$resource` API method.

**Code**

```
dogsResource.delete({id: $stateParams.dogId}).$promise.then(function(data)//Success
     console.log(value);
},
function(httpResponse){ //Error
    console.log(httpResponse);
});
```

Comment: @CamiloR could you add your `dogsResource` code inside your question?

Comment: there it is the code for the resource, Hope it helps.

Comment: @CamiloR try changing your `$resource` object to `$resource("http://localhost:5000/dogs/:id",{ },{update: {method: "PUT"}})` as you are using same property name `id`  while passing its value.