# How to handle factory service errors in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Factory code**

```
app.factory('abcFactory', function ($http, Config, $log) {
    var serviceURL = Config.baseURL + '/results';
    return{
        results:function() {
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: serviceURL,
                timeout: Config.httpTimeout
            }).then(function(response) {
                    return response;  

                },  function(reason) {
                    $log.error("Request Failed: ", reason)
                });

            return promise;
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller code**

```
app.controller('abcController',function ($scope, $log,abcFactory, Config)
{

        abcFactory.results(function(data){
            $scope.results =data;
        },function(response)
        {
          console.log("response"+response);

          if(response.status === 0)
          {
              console.log("gotcha");
               $scope.serviceTimedoutError(response.data, response.status, response.config);
          } else
          {
                console.log("gotcha");
                $scope.serviceFailure(response.data, response.status, response.config);
          }


        });
});
```

`$scope.results` populates fine when service has returned good response.

And, when there is an error I can see on console the error message coming from factory code's log saying `"Request Failed: blah blah "`.

**My issue:**
When there is an error, why I am not seeing error message in controller, it is not even printing `"gotcha"` in browser console. I need error details in controller, so that I can show it on view. I don't want to pass `$scope` in factory.

What wrong I am doing in Controller code?

If I am not wrong, I am doing something in line of [AngularJS Failed Resource GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598097/angularjs-failed-resource-get)
but not getting desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want the `results` function to take callbacks, but its arguments list is currently empty. You are returning the promis though.

So either change the call in the controller to:

```
abcFactory.results()
  .success(function() { ... })
  .error(function() { ... })
```

Or change the results function itself:

```
results: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
  var promise = $http(...).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
  return promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your second option. I still don't get error msg in controller. Do you want me to change something in Controller code as well?

Comment: See the $http docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http. If you're using the `success` and `error` callbacks, they receive different arguments than the callbacks to `then`. [data, status, headers, config].

Comment: +1.. though this way it works. But now, I have to shift processing logic of response to controller, which I wanted to keep in factory. I was looking to solve it without having to use `.success()` and `.error()` in controller. I will wait for some more responses on this, before accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Deprecation Notice**
The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.